# GIT GUI (Windows) - move from Unstaged to Staged

Tags: git, user-interface

I have a project with 10.000 files, which I want to push to repository. But before push I have to move it from Unstaged list to Staged. Stupid problem that I don't see any button like "Move all", it does not understand drag'n'drop, I can move files only one-by-one? Why and how to solve this strange problem?

Comment: Maybe consider using GitExtensions? There's Stage All certainly, I am not sure about original Git Gui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean `git gui`? Then just select all unstages files using mouse: click first one, scroll to the last, hold the shift key and click the last file. Then stage.

However, `git add -A` is much easier than gui magic.

Comment: Do you mean git gui? Then just select all unstages files using mouse: click first one, scroll to the last, hold the shift key and click the last file. Then stage. - it doen't work

Comment: Works for me. Not sure then what you are doing, give more information.

Comment: I think the issue is the "10,000" files which is a LOT of scrolling ;-)

Comment: @PhilipOakley You can scroll fast by dragging scrollbar. Anyway, I don't understand what's wrong with command line...

Comment: @kan, "what's wrong with command line" - I think it's a religious thing ;-). The 'wimp' and 'cli' approaches are fairly orthogonal for most folks, so swapping between is a bit of a wrench.

Comment: @PhilipOakley once then you need to commit 10000 files, I think it is possible to use more appropriate approach. I don't think he will change 10000 files daily.

Comment: @kan, While I agree with your point, you never can tell what unusual and apparently perverse workflow he is having to work under. Who knows what some senior manager has ordered without realising the consequences! ;-) Most [big company] workflows are based on the issues that were present when they built the Titanic (protect the master document, its irreplaceable, while men and materials are secondary). The OP may just need to learn the cli and have git-gui, gitk, and bash all open at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

In git-gui, there are 2 methods to move all the files from Unstaged to Staged.

1) Press Ctrl+I which will move all the Unstaged files to staged files

2) Click "Stage Changed" button in the bottom panel above "Signoff" and "Commit"

[image]

Comment: Surely this is the answer? The guy asked for git GUI. Worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for choosing certain files, e.g. one by one, is to click the files icon on the left of the file name in the Unstaged Changes area and it is moved to the Staged Changes (Will Commit) area.

This is an answer applicable to the question title. The answer is not applicable to the body of the question which mentions ~10000 files .. This may however be the answer that a person that searches and finds the question title is looking for.

[image]

Comment: I asked it more than 7 years ago :)

Comment: Still a relevant question ! …  I think the writers of Git Gui should have coded for click or double click on the file name to move to staged (rather than having to click the small icon) Otherwise everyone new to Git Gui is going to have the exact same question as this one, in general, for individual file move to Staged !?!

Comment: I will subscribe to the Git community and suggest this improvement for Git Gui !